# Subset data with a weighting factor

Tags: r, subset

I am trying to subset a data frame and use a column value as the weighting factor.

For example, lets say we have these data.

```
set.seed(123)
Data <- data.frame(x1 = sample(c(0,1),100, replace = T), x2 = round(runif(100, min=0, max=100),0), Prob = round(runif(100),2))
head(Data)

> head(Data)
  x1 x2 Prob
1  0 60 0.24
2  1 33 0.96
3  0 49 0.60
4  1 95 0.52
5  1 48 0.40
6  0 89 0.88
```

where x1 and x2 are simple place holders and `Prob` represents the probability that the values in the data are invalid or could not been observed. From `Data`  I want to generate 5 different subsets.  The new data frames will contain 90, 80, 70, 60, and 50 percent of the rows contained in `Data`. Said differently, I want to remove 10, 20, 30, 40 and 50 percent of the data, and make 5 new subsets.

The difficulty is that I want to use the `Prob` field as a weighting factor.  Rows with a higher `Prob` value should occur less in the new data subsets.

For example, a `Prob` of 0.24 will have 24% chance of NOT being selected when the new data subsets are created.  A `Prob` value of 0.96 would have a 96% of NOT being and a new data subset.

Ideally, I would select a random subset from Data to make the new data frames.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `sample`? You can specify a probability vector. I'm not entirely sure how it works, but I think you'd want something like:

`new_data <- Data[sample(nrow(Data), N, prob = (1 - Data$Prob), replace = F),]`

where N is the sample size you want. A quick histogram shows it behaves like what you want, but like I said, I'm not 100% sure on how it uses that vector.

Comment: @goodtimeslim, the question is vague, but I don't think the OP wants to use `sample`. It's weighting needs to add up to one, but the OP's probs add up to be greater than 1. I think using a `rbinom` would work better.

Comment: `sample`'s probs don't need to sum to one, they just need to be real probabilities. The code I provided will run with his data; whether it's what he wants, I don't know.
Here, I generated data like his, with 100 observations, with probabilities as a sequence from 0 to 1, in .1 increments. I sampled 25 like above, and then took a histogram of the probabilities in the sample: http://i.imgur.com/4Cmcwuw.png

Comment: @goodtimeslim Thanks for the quick reply.  I have been working with the prob argument to the sample function and it accomplishing what I had intended.  Thanks.  Post as an answer...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use something like the following:

```
new_data <- Data[sample(nrow(Data), N, prob = (1 - Data$Prob), replace = F),]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do. However, I think you want to use the `rbinom` function.

To simulate one outcome, you would use this code:

```
simOne = sapply(1 - Data$Prob, rbinom, size = 1, n = 1)
head(simOne)
# [1] 1 0 1 0 1 0
```

The `1 -` is needed because you prob of failure, but you need prob of successes. Next use `simOne` in your original matrix:

```
Data[simOne > 0, ]
head(Data[simOne > 0, ] )
#  x1 x2 Prob
#   0 60 0.24
#   0 49 0.60
#   1 48 0.40
#   1 91 0.36
#   1 61 0.29
#   1 41 0.17
```

I am no sure what you are trying to do next based upon your question. If you clarify, I'd be happy to edit my answer with your next step. If you want to generate many different samples, your code would work quicker if you sampled everything at once:

nSamples = 10
   ## Simluate probabilty of inclusion
   simMany = sapply(1 - Data$Prob, rbinom, size = 1, n = nSamples)

Note that you may need to transpose (`t(simMany)`) depending up how you want to use it.